# data-XXX does not return what it is supposed to. Keeps coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running the following javascript:

```
$('.change-month').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).data('month') == true)
    show_last_month = true;
  else
    show_last_month = false;
  console.log($(this).html());
  $.post('index.php?module=MTDTransactions&action=esajaxContactData',
    { id: user_id,
      show_last_month: show_last_month }, 
    function(data){
        $('#transaction').html(data);
        // resizes IFrame
      var iFrame = window.parent.document.getElementById('dashboardContent');
      iFrame.style.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    });
});
```

`$(this).data('month')` is undefined. Here is my element:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default MTDtransactions-filter-btn change-month" data-month="true" >This Month's</button>
```

Oh yeah I a running jquery-1.11.0 and the above is enclosed in a document.ready function

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue (http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7dpve7jn/) — are you sure that the `data-month` attribute has not been modified or updated in any way after DOM ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `data()` method only pulls the value stored from an element's `data-*` attributes when the element is first explored within the DOM. Any changes are not monitored.

If you wish to get the `data-month` value with jQuery, you can use `attr()` instead:

```
$(this).attr('data-month') == "true"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned the above element is loaded onto the screen by way of an ajax call and hence not monitored. Thanks Mr. Donnelly!